# xslt transformation to fo: Generating numberd headings with different formatting

Tags: xslt, numbers, xsl-fo, heading

I try to transform a XML structure with XSLT into a FO-script. I have trouble with numbered headings. 
I have a XML-structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
   <type1>
      <heading>Topic level1</heading>
      <paragraph>Text</paragraph>
   </type1>
   <type2>
      <heading>Topic level1</heading>
      <paragraph>Text</paragraph>
   </type2>
   <type1>
      <heading>Topic level1</heading>
      <type1>
         <heading>Topic level2</heading>
         <paragraph>Text</paragraph>
         </type1>
           <heading>Topic level3</heading>
           <paragraph>Text</paragraph>
         </type1>
      </type1>
   </type1>
...
</document>
```

The original XML-structure is deeper nested and has more elements.
Right now I have a template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="type1/heading | type2/heading | type3/heading | type4/heading | 
 type5/heading | type6/heading | type7/heading">
   <fo:block font-weight="bold" font-size="13pt" space-after="5mm" id="{generate-
   Id()}">
      <xsl:number count="type1| type2| type3| type4| type5| type6 | type7"
       format="1.1" level="multiple"/>&#160;
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

The output is basically ok. But all headings have the same style parameters. I want to have different stylings for the different heading levels.
For example like this:

## 1. Topic level1

Text

## 2. Topic level1

Text

## 3. Topic level1

Text

### 3.1 Topic level2

Text

#### 3.1.1 Topic level3

Text

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you (a) fix your input example to be well-formed XML, and (b) post your expected result **as code**?

Comment: There are many ways to do what you wish, but you would need to show more of your templates, specifically what after them or what else may be in the "type" element. You could apply the styling in matches for each "type" element and let the heading inherit that style.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the level of the current heading by counting either the number of dots in the result of `<xsl:number>` or the number of ancestors of type1 | type2, etc.